# Cannot connect to ec2 instances with pem key on yosemite machines

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, osx-yosemite

So I am setting up two new macs (yosemite) for ssh-ing into out EC2 instances and the have the same issue.

When I copy and paste the .pem key from amazon into the .ssh/ folder, then try to ssh in with:

```
sudo ssh -i /users/me/.ssh/key_pair_1_8_5_2015.pem ubuntu@54.186.XXX.XX
```

I get the following:

```
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /users/colin/.ssh/key_pair_1_8_5_2015.pem
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Saving password to keychain failed
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

which results in a popup box asking for the

```
enter you password for the key pair "key_pair..."
```

Of course you don't have a key pair for the pem keys, and I certainly have not set one up previously, so this makes no sense. From reading around this seems to be the default error for a whole host of issue.

I know I have permissions set correctly, and I know that the users I am trying to connect to are OK.

I have set up multiple other macs in the same fashion and connected to many ec2 development servers this way.

But since both macs have identical errors, I suspect it is something to do with the client OS that is preventing this. They are freshly wiped macs that have had little previous configuration (although I did set up ssh keys as normal), so I am wondering if there is something else that needs configuring before I can proceed.

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1):

I've had no issues with yosemite or el capitan with EC2 keys. It's not about the OS, it's about the openssh versions.

Ensure your AMI is correct, some people have had issues with building AMIs and leaving old keys on them, rendering launch with new ones not working. Also ensure your permissions are in fact 0400 or 0600 on the private key.

Based on a hunch though I think your key is corrupt:

```
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
```

This seems more like the key was saved incorrectly.

Also: You probably shouldn't be running `sudo` to ssh into it.

Comment: It indeed seems like the file is not PEM at all. And the `ssh` assumes it needs to be decrypted to be readable, so it asks for a passphrase.